# jquery affecting all the html elements with same class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

for last few days I'm working on a project, now in this project, I have a sidebar with buttons like this

```
<div class="btn">
   Button 1
</div>
<div class="btn">
   Button 2
</div>
<div class="btn">
   Button 3
</div>
```

Also, I have some javascript for mouseenter event code like this

```
$(function).ready(function(){
    $('.btn').mouseenter(function(){
        $('.btn').css('color', 'red');   
    });
});
```

Now the problem is this javascript code is changing all the elements with the same class. I don't want it. I want to change only one button.

For example, if hover on the first button, the javascript code should change the color of the first button only, not other buttons

For some reason, i can not use CSS for this case

So can anyone help me to solve this problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to reference the element specifically with $(this) otherwise all elements with class ".btn" will change:

```
$('.btn').mouseenter(function () {

    $(this).css('color', 'red');

});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to specify which element with the same class name, you can use `.eq()`. `$("div.btn")` would mean all `<div>` elements with the class `btn`. However, if you do `$("div.btn").eq(0)`, it would mean the first `<div>` element with the class `btn`. Similarly, `.eq(1)` for the second element and so on.

Answer (score 0):

It should be like this.

```
$(function).ready(function(){ $('.btn').mouseenter(function(){ $(this).css('color', 'red'); }); });
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".btn").mouseover(function(){
$(this).css('color','red')
});
$(".btn").mouseleave(function(){
$(this).css('color','#000000')
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="btn">
   Button 1
</div>
<div class="btn">
   Button 2
</div>
<div class="btn">
   Button 3
</div>
```